# MySql select all rows in one table based on MAX value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, max

I want to be able to get all the data from table 1 and table 3 below but in addition to this I also want to get the latest application stage from table 2.  The latest application stage is determined by getting the max stage_date for each application.

**Table 1: applications**

```
id | applicant_id | col_x | col_y | col_z
-----------------------------------------
10   300            a       b       c    
11   310            a       b       c    
12   320            a       b       c    
13   330            a       b       c    
14   340            a       b       c
```

**Table 2: application_progress**

```
id | application_id | application_stage | stage_date | stage_notes
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    10               DRAFT               2013-01-01   (NULL)   
2    10               APPLICATION         2013-01-14   (NULL)   
3    10               PHASE1              2013-01-30   (NULL)
4    11               DRAFT               2013-01-01   (NULL)  
4    12               DRAFT               2013-01-01   (NULL) 
5    13               DRAFT               2013-01-01   (NULL)  
6    14               DRAFT               2013-01-01   (NULL)   
7    14               APPLICATION         2013-01-14   (NULL)
```

**EDIT: third table**

**Table 3: applicants**

```
id  | applicant_name | applicant_address | programme_id 
------------------------------------------------------
300   Applicant 1      abc                 1    
310   Applicant 2      xyz                 2    
320   Applicant 3      xyz                 2    
330   Applicant 4      xyz                 2    
340   Applicant 5      xyz                 2
```

**Returned data set**

```
applicant_id | applicant_name | current_stage
---------------------------------------------------------
300            Applicant 1      PHASE1
310            Applicant 2      DRAFT
320            Applicant 3      DRAFT 
330            Applicant 4      DRAFT   
340            Applicant 5      APPLICATION
```

Am struggling with this one and would appreciate any help.

PS. Tried to put an example of sqlfiddle but it's down at the minute.  I'll update this with the sqlfiddle when it's back up if haven't had an answer before this.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far in your query - post it direclty here, no need for SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select application_stage
        from application_progress ap
        where ap.application_id = a.id
        order by stage_date desc
        limit 1
       ) MostRecentStage
from applications a;
```

EDIT:

You can joining in the applicant data with something like this::

```
select a.*, aa.*,
       (select application_stage
        from application_progress ap
        where ap.application_id = a.id
        order by stage_date desc
        limit 1
       ) MostRecentStage
from applications a join
     applicant aa
     on a.applicant_id = aa.id;
```

Comment: Thank Gordon.  I am trying to extend this to introduce a third table so that I can get an applicants current status and have tweaked your code as follows:

`SELECT applicants.*,
 (SELECT application_stage
 FROM application_progress
 JOIN applications ON application_progress.application.id = applications.id
 WHERE application_progress.application_id = applications.id
 ORDER BY application_progress.state_date DESC
 LIMIT 1
 ) AS current_stage,
FROM applicants;`

but it's not working for me.  How would I tweak your code to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianWalls . . . I don't see a third table in your code.  Just an unnecessary join to `applications` in the subquery.

Comment: I added the third table to the original post.  I want to get all applicants from the applicants table along with the current stage of their application?

Do I not need to then join applications and application_progress in the subquery while selecting all from applicants in the main query?