# php : one to many relationship get the latest row of the many relation table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is having deposit's (table: deposit) another table is having comments for deposits (table: comment).

Both table are linked by 1 to many relationship ie, one deposit may have many comments.

Below query gives all comments but *I want only the last comment* (comments table has auto generated id)

```
SELECT 
    D.missing_deposit_amount,
    D.missing_deposit_date,
    C.comment
    FROM deposit AS D
    LEFT JOIN comments AS C on 
    C.md_id=D.md_id 
    WHERE 1
```

How can i extend this query to give only the last comment corresponding to deposit?

Comment: What defines the "last" comment? Is there a datetime field?

Comment: `WHERE 1` Whats that doing? *"How can i extend this query to give only the last comment corresponding to deposit?"* See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql select all rows in one table based on MAX value in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790011/mysql-select-all-rows-in-one-table-based-on-max-value-in-another-table)

Comment: @RaymondNijland, after `WHERE 1` we have some code, i removed those for easier understading, you can see full query here prnt.sc/mxrtwy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the last one using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT D.missing_deposit_amount, D.missing_deposit_date,
       C.comment
FROM deposit D LEFT JOIN
     comments C on 
     ON C.md_id = D.md_id AND
        c.id = (SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM comments c2 WHERE c2.md_id = c.md_id);
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . "(comments table has auto generated id)".

Comment: Never readed that line in the question then your query indeed seams to be solid approach, never mind mine comment then.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i am getting this error can you let me know what im wrong here https://prnt.sc/mxrtwy

Comment: FYI : in question i changed table names for simple understanding

Comment: @arun . . . Your code actually looks okay.  I don't see an obvious issue.